# WP link for reset password is not received

Tags: authentication

I used my existing password but that did not work.
So I asked for a new password.
Your Email, with your link, has not been sent

Comment: Set SMTP mail configuration and try again may be its will  be work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `mail()` PHP function is disabled on your server and sending emails silently fails. So either check your hosting setup or try using SMTP with this plugin for example : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the main issue first

**wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

**functions.php**

```
// define the wp_mail_failed callback 
function action_wp_mail_failed($wp_error) 
{
    return error_log(print_r($wp_error, true));
}

// add the action 
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);
```

For more detail read this article [LINK](https://www.codeforest.net/debugging-wp-mail-like-a-boss-debugger)